# html table set some cell text colours based on value

Tags: html, html-table

I have an html table and in a particular column the text is either set to 'Y' or 'N'. I'm wondering if it is possible to set the colour of the text to Red programmatically on load if the value is'N'?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>N</td>
        <td>Y</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Coder 2, see my answer. If you can use jQuery, this will accomplish it the way you describe.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it's easy:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table_id td.y_n').each(function(){
        if ($(this).text() == 'N') {
            $(this).css('background-color','#f00');
        }
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<table id="table_id">
 <tr><th>Question</th><th>Y/N?</th></tr>
 <tr><td>I am me.</td><td class="y_n">Y</td></tr>
 <tr><td>I am him.</td><td class="y_n">N</td></tr>
 <tr><td>I am not sure.</td><td class="y_n">Y</td></tr>
 <tr><td>This is a table.</td><td class="y_n">Y</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Note: I tested the above file and it works. Copy to your desktop, save as yn.html, and run in a browser.

EDIT: To accomplish with a pure selector and not rely on the if statement...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#table_id td.y_n:contains('N')").css('background-color','#fcc');
});
```

This was following Tyler Holien's answer. This would be the better way to do it, since it doesn't involve so many function calls and is more expressive in less code. NOTE: Unfortunately, do not use this version if there would be other content that may contain N's and should not be selected, since contains will select all text that has N in it, not JUST the 'N'-only text.

Comment: @Coder 2 - See my edit with the revised $(document).ready() code. I would use the last version.

Comment: Ok, great. I would have thought the first option was better though as 'N' is all I'm interested in setting. Not sure how the 'contains' functions as that is new to me. I'm hoping it finding only though containing just 'N' and not those that have 'N' plus other text.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, stick with the first version if you don't have a column (by classname) that would only feed selectable text based on one of two values (Y, N). Otherwise, if for instance that column had NEIN or Bind or whatnot, it would select it as well. Good catch.

Comment: Oh, and I removed that second line. I was using that to test it to make sure it was working like I expected.

Comment: If you want to use a pure selector, you can always extend jQuery as in [this post](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/jquery-regex-filter/). I've created an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TSDUf/).

Comment: Interesting. I made two from that, match and matchi: http://jsfiddle.net/VEqYq/ There are two selectors, match() and matchi(), with matchi() being case-insensitive. I included a number of examples to show how different matches would work. jQuery should include the regex and match functions... :D And I think Coder 2 should probably stick with the if statement, for simplicity.

Comment: I got that working thanks. However I now need it to work for rows that aren't hard coded. ie. That gets the N from a asp:Label within the td with the text value obtained from an Eval. Any ideas?

Comment: I like second solution on pure js. It works fine now in 2018 on all my browsers. Better to split it in a different answer :)

Answer (score 7):

Try the following CSS:

```
td[value="N"] {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: No, doesn't seem to respond to that.

Comment: It worked for me in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4r3Ue/). Could you post some example code?

Comment: @Tyler - Coder 2 is probably not using the value attribute; this is not an officially supported attribute for TD's, so that's not unusual. Interesting approach, though.

Comment: Oh right, yes it works in that example. However maybe I didn't word it well by referring to it as 'value'. I meant the text in the cell.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: No worries, I should have worded the question better. I learnt something from your answer though thanks.

Comment: @Tyler Holien - see my edit, inspired by your attempt. It looks like contents() could do it in pure CSS, but you would need to go through some cruft to do so, and there is still shaky legacy browser support. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did

```
    $('.dataframe td').each(function(){
        var num = parseFloat($(this).text());
        if (num > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('success');
            //$(this).css('color','Green');
        } else if (num < 0) {
            $(this).addClass('danger');
            //$(this).css('color','Red');
        }
    });
```