# How to introduce class ID's into data that is imported from a CSV file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, csv, html-table

So here's the input

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh">
    <title>CSV File to HTML Table Using AJAX jQuery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: black;
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <div id="transaction_history_table">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "transaction_history_edited.csv",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                var transaction_history_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
                var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered">';
                for (var count = 0; count < transaction_history_data.length; count++) {
                    var cell_data = transaction_history_data[count].split(",");
                    table_data += '<tr>';
                    for (var cell_count = 0; cell_count < cell_data.length; cell_count++) {
                        if (count === 0) {
                            table_data += '<th>' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</th>';
                        }
                        else {
                            table_data += '<td>' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</td>';
                        }
                    }
                    table_data += '</tr>';
                }
                table_data += '</table>';
                $('#transaction_history_table').html(table_data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dja5C.jpg)
So I'm wanting to far right column, the one that has some cells start with a minus symbol, to have their font turned red, and if it does not have a minus symbol, it has it's font turned green.
But just for the cells in those columns.

So I googled around, and all of them seemed to be basicly like this.
[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880595/html-table-set-some-cell-text-colours-based-on-value)

Where you have to designate the column or the cell it's own class ID, that would be fine if the data originated inside the html file, like it does in the examples.
But my data comes from the CSV file, so hoping to get some pointers on how to give give a column it's own class ID?

Comment: You can select all the `<tr>` elements, go through them using `forEach`, and select, say, the fifth child of the element (using something like `el.children[4]`).

Comment: Sorry, not sure what el in el.children[4] means, all I can see is it's in cell or else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your and screenshot, I'd assumed that the last row is at index 10,
and the data is always int.

I would add the conditional block like this, and add the class.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "transaction_history_edited.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            var transaction_history_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
            var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered">';
            for (var count = 0; count < transaction_history_data.length; count++) {
                var cell_data = transaction_history_data[count].split(",");
                table_data += '<tr>';
                for (var cell_count = 0; cell_count < cell_data.length; cell_count++) {
                    if (count === 0) {
                        table_data += '<th>' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</th>';
                    }
                    else {
                        //assuming the last cell is the index #10 by looking at your screenshot
                        if (cell_count === 10) {
                            table_data += '<td class="' + (parseInt(cell_data[cell_count]) > 0 ? 'green' : 'red') + '">' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</td>';
                        } else {
                            table_data += '<td>' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</td>';    
                        }
                    }
                }
                table_data += '</tr>';
            }
            table_data += '</table>';
            $('#transaction_history_table').html(table_data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't have any effect.

Comment: I'm getting closer, I realized the CSS component was missing, so i added                                     ```.red {color:red}
    .green {color:green}```

Comment: Sorry that's so sloppy, it won't let me just create a new line, this just turns every single cell red though.

Comment: I noticed your answer doesn't contain the minus symbol? Doesn't it need that?

Comment: I think I see, if one is above zero then it's not negative.

Comment: I don't think it's an int, I think it's a string

Comment: If it's a string that would explain why it can't tell the difference?

Comment: Yes, in my first iteration, I assumed it was INT. I updated the code, now it will parse the string to INT.

Comment: Thanks so much, never knew about the JavaScript parseInt() Function until now.